# How to save user values without logging in and then add data fields in the current user value from some other activity?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a game app in android kotlin using firestore.When user first enters app he enters a "name" which I want to save in firestore.
When he submits name he is taken to next activity screen which has 2 options host n join.

If he clicks host he should enter the gameroomname and click host button.

On clicking host button the gameroom name should be stored along with the name entered on first screen for the particular current user.

I have stored username in firestore but I am not sure how can I find that same username and add gameroomname for the same user on my third screen.

How can I achieve doing this or what can I refer in order to do this?

I have added the skelton pictures of screens of the app below:

1)First screen where user enters username:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSTyT.png)

2)Second screen where user chooses host or join:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Of2.png)

3)When user chooses host from second screen he lands on this screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbvy4.png)

Code i used to store username:

```js
mFirestore= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
gamingSubmit.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    val gamingUserName:String=gamingName.text.toString()
    val userMap=HashMap<String,Any>()
    userMap.put("gamingName",gamingUserName)
         mFirestore.collection("AllUsers").document("host").collection("hostids").document(gamingUserName).set(userMap)
         .addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener {
              Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Successfully submitted name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
          }).addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener {e->
              val error=e.message                                                             Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Error:"+error,
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
          })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already setup firestore in your project (if not you can use this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)), you only need to initialize the instance, something like:

```
// Access a Cloud Firestore instance from your Activity
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
```

Then you can save the values using:

```
// Create a new user with a game room
val userRoom = HashMap<String, Any>()
userRoom["name"] = "Ada"
userRoom["gameroom"] = "Lovelace"

// Add a new document with a generated ID
db.collection("userRooms")
    .add(userRoom)
    .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.id)
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
        Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e)
    }
```

The above code will create a new document with that has two fields: a `name` and a `gameroom`. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) more details on how to manipulate data in firestore.

Comment: I had done the above way to add username ,but my question actually was how can i add the gameroomname to the same user from third screen.My question was not very clear,hence i have updated my question.Please check.

Comment: You have at least two options: 1. save the user and the game room like presented my answer when on the third screen. 2. Save the user on the first screen and get a hold to the reference, then on the third screen perform an update with the game room.

Comment: Ok.I will try this.